# Unable to evaluate reasonable max expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the following statement:

```
Max[0, Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 \[Theta]]]]
```

You'll find that Mathematica won't evaluate this, because it doesn't know the range of $\theta$. Okay, that makes sense, so change it to:

```
Simplify[Max[0, Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 \[Theta]]]], {0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 \[Pi]}]
```

This evaluates happily. As it should. But then consider this not-impactful adjustment:

```
Simplify[Max[0, Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 \[Theta]]]/
  Sqrt[2]], {0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 \[Pi]}]
```

This doesn't evaluate. I don't know why; because it seems quite obvious that it should be exactly the same as the previous case, right? (The constant factor of `1/Sqrt[2]` can't change the fact that it is still $\geq 0$). Any thoughts on how to fix this? Of course, in my case I want to actually keep the `Max` ..., but I don't know the exact form of the other side, so I can't just arbitrarily remove constants ...

Comment: `Simplify[Max[0, 
  Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 \[Theta]]]/Sqrt[2]]], {0 <= \[Theta] <= 
   2 \[Pi]}]
` seems to work.

Comment: ...and what happens if you use `FullSimplify[]` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the Accept, but I encourage all users to wait 24 hours before Accepting as answer so that other users have a chance to read and answer the question before it appears concluded.  Quick Accepts may prevent the posting of other, potentially better answers.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard; I did try and un-accept yesterday, but for some reason actions on this site occasionally don't work (like voting and commenting.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many potential simplifications that `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not make, presumably because they are deemed too costly to attempt.

In this case it appears that parts are at too deep a level for the required simplifications to be made:

```
expr = Max[0, Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 t]]/Sqrt[2]];
simp = FullSimplify[#, {0 <= t <= 2 Pi}] &;

simp @ expr
```

> ```
> Max[0, 1/Sqrt[Csc[2 t]^2]]
> ```

If you apply the simplification function to all the subexpressions further transformations are made:

```
simp //@ expr
```

> ```
> Abs[Sin[2 t]]
> ```

Comment: Nice, a very rare occurrence of `MapAll`!

Comment: Indeed, `MapAll[]` is always a good idea when simplifying tricky things.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks.  [I try to find uses for it.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5747742/618728)

Comment: Funny enough, your solution does not work with `Simplify`, but the less specific (and inferior) `Simplify[Max[0, Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Cos[4 \[Theta]]]/Sqrt[2]]], {0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 \[Pi]}] ` does?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: @Yves I am not surprised; there is a large element of chance involved in this and I certainly do not mean to imply that `//@` is a panacea -- far from it in fact.  It only *so happens* that it produces the needed string of transformations in this case.  [Search MathGroup for `VOISimplify`](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/search/?q=VOISimplify) for a good illustration of the order dependence of `Simplify` that often manifests as apparent capriciousness.

Comment: An insightful statement by Andrzej Kozlowski in that thread: *... there are just too many different groupings and rearrangements that would have to be tried to get to a simpler form. Moreover, Mathematica will only apply a transformation if it immediately leads to a decrease in complexity. Sometimes the only way to transform an expression to a simpler form is by first transforming it to a more complex one ...*

Comment: BTW, awesome gravatar. It becomes your new status ;-)

Comment: @Yves thanks, I think. :o)