# Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, letter-makes-difference

Here is the example:

```
Simplify[x + y, x + y == a]
Simplify[x + y, x + y == 5]
```

Mathematica 9 output:

```
x+y
5
```

I expect the complexity of `a` to be lower than complexity of `Plus[x,y]`, and the result of the first line should be `a`.

Even if I specify `ComplexityFunction` explicitly:

```
Simplify[x + y, x + y == a, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

I still get `x+y` as a result. It's however obvious that `LeafCount[x+y]` is greater than `LeafCount[a]`.

Why does Simplify ignore `x+y==a` but uses `x+y==5`? How can I define the former assumption in a right way?

Comment: It is interesting that `Simplify[x y, x y == a]` returns `a`.

Comment: As does `Simplify[x^2+y^2,x^2+y^2==a]`, and `Simplify[x+y,x+y==Cos[a]]` returns `Cos[a]`

Comment: ... and, `Simplify[x + y, x + y == Unevaluated[a]] ` gives `a`...?

Comment: `Simplify[x+y, x+y == boo[]]` also gives `boo[]`. Strange.

Comment: It's something I've seen posted before, but can't find. It has to do with the fact that `Simplify` seems to have a preference for alphabetical order in sums. So you can get the expected result by replacing `a` with any symbol that lexically comes *after* `x` and `y`. For example, use `Simplify[x + y, x + y == xPlusY]` or just `Simplify[x + y,x + y==z]`. It probably tries substitutions not in all permutations but only in alphabetical order when sums are involved.

Comment: Related questions: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4575, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4522.

Comment: @Jens Your observation looks too important not to put it in an answer even if it is not a *full* answer.

Comment: A similar issue was discussed in this question: [mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11111](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11111)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We can see from the examples in the comments to the question that `Simplify` (and `FullSimplify` which builds on it) doesn't try all permutations of substitutions. That's probably justified in general to keep the computational effort from exploding, but in your example it leads to the quirky behavior that the **variable names** affect the result of the simplification.

For example, you get

```
Clear[a, z];
Simplify[x + y, x + y == a]

(* ==> x + y *)

Simplify[x + y, x + y == z]

(* ==> z *)
```

The only difference is that the last assumption uses a variable name that comes lexically *after* the names which you would like to replace.

I think the reason for this is that *Mathematica* tries substitutions in sums only in a specific sequence dictated by the alphabetical order of the variables it encounters.

My heuristic conclusion from this would be that assumptions in which you would like variables to be substituted by new names should have the *new* names chosen such that they come lexically after the "old" names.

If this doesn't work for you, the best alternative would be to do the elimination explicitly using `Eliminate`.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a [little tool from Adam Strzebonski](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Jan/msg00237.html) that deals with the issue that Jens describes.

```
VOISimplify[vars_, expr_, assum_: True] := 
 Module[{perm, ee, best}, perm = Permutations[vars];
  ee = (FullSimplify @@ ({expr, assum} /. Thread[vars -> #])) & /@ perm;
  best = Sort[Transpose[{LeafCount /@ ee, ee, perm}]][[1]];
  best[[2]] /. Thread[best[[3]] -> vars]]
```

Now:

```
VOISimplify[{a, x, y}, x + y, x + y == a]
```

> ```
> a
> ```

Comment: It looks like WRI is aware of this strange behavior for already seven years. [Here is the link](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Apr/msg00384.html)

Comment: @NickStranniy That could very well be where I first read about this problem, too. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Cute, but it increases execution time by a factor Factorial[Length[vars]].

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, and Adam explicitly states exactly that.  I think it's kind of the point: to consider all variable orderings gets very expensive very quickly.  I suppose optimization may be possible but I am just the messenger here.