# Why doesn't FullSimplify get rid of the common factor in this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

`FullSimplify` does not get rid of the `z` factor in the following expression:

```
FullSimplify[(E^(-I x) y z + (1 + E^(I y)) (x + y) z)/z, z != 0]
```

Upon removing a single piece of the expression, such as the first `y` factor or the `1+` in the brackets, the simplification suddenly succeeds. As far as I can tell it is only this special combination of variables that fails.

Is there any obvious problem with simplifying this?
Is there a way to tweak the `FullSimplify` function to make it succeed? (this is just a part of a longer expression - and I want to avoid looking for such problems manually).

I'm using *Mathematica* version 9.0.0.0 on Win7 64 bit.

Comment: How about `Simplify[(E^(-I x) y z + (1 + E^(I y)) (x + y) z)/z // Factor]` ?

Comment: Maybe `FullSimplify[Expand@(E^(-I x) y z + (1 + E^(I y)) (x + y) z)/z, z != 0]`?

Comment: Or `FullSimplify[Cancel[(E^(-I x) y z + (1 + E^(I y)) (x + y) z)/z], 
 z != 0]`. What I find interesting is that if you use e.g. `(x+a)` instead of `(x+y)` in your original expression, it seems to work directly...

Comment: All these suggestions work. I'm not sure how to judge this, but the one involving `Cancel` seems like the most direct. As for an explanation for this strange behavior, I guess I shouldn't hold my breath. @PinguinDirk - do you want to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the comment above and requested by the OP as an answer, I can only offer a workaround:

```
FullSimplify[Cancel[(E^(-I x) y z + (1 + E^(I y)) (x + y) z)/z], z != 0]
```

Also, I'd like to note again that using e.g. `(x+a)` instead of `(x+y)` in the original expression seems to make it work, out of the box (without `Cancel`)

Comment: (+1) Interesting observation about `a`. That seems to indicate that the culprit is the same as in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/245)

Comment: @Jens: ah, I wasn't aware of the question - interesting indeed. I did try various expressions instead of `(x+y)` there and couldn't figure out any pattern in Mathematica's behaviour. Interesting indeed.