# Abs and ^2 within Solve: curious speed characteristics

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I was playing around with the Solve function recently and found a behavior I couldn't explain. The equations I'm working with look like

```
Solve[{
Abs[(x - I y)/(x + I y)] == 4.5, 
Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}, {x, y}]
```

Which computes quite quickly. The variations I looked at add a squaring (^2) to different terms, eg.

```
Solve[{
Abs[(x^2 - I y)/(x + I y)] == 4.5, 
Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}, {x, y}]

Solve[{
Abs[(x - I y^2)/(x + I y)] == 4.5, 
Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}, {x, y}]

Solve[{
Abs[(x - I y)/(x + I y^2)] == 4.5, 
Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}, {x, y}]
```

All solve quite quickly. However,

```
Solve[{
Abs[(x - I y)/(x^2 + I y)] == 4.5, 
Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}, {x, y}]
```

has been running for quite a while now, and my hopes of it completing at all are low. But it seems so similar to the previous three variations! Why is this fourth system, though ostensibly similar to the other three, so much more difficult for Mathematica to Solve?

In case it matters, I'm running v11 on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you considered preprocessing with `ComplexExpand[]`?

Comment: To wit: `ComplexExpand /@ {Abs[(x - I y)/(x^2 + I y)] == 4.5, 
  Abs[x + I y]^2 == 2}` and then `Solve[%,{x,y}]`, evaluates rapidly.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't know about ComplexExpand. So useful!

Comment: @Feyre, it gives the wrong answer though, in version 11

Comment: You can replace `x` with `z` and get a rapid result. Sometimes altering the lexical ordering of symbols in the expression helps Mathematica choose better transformations.

Comment: Related to Simon's comment see: [(17926)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/121) and [(83756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83756/121).  @Simon based on the links above would you consider this question a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yeah I think it's essentially a duplicate. The underlying issue is the same.

Comment: This question was one vote from being closed as "a simple mistake" -- instead letting that happen, which makes this post a dead-end, I closed it as a "duplicate" of a related question that while not a *duplicate* does *have an answer* as to why this happens.