# Simplify terms with delayed and immediate function definitions

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, variable-definitions

Say I want to define a function `f`with input `x` but also involving parameter `p` not yet specified:

```
f[x_] := p^x
```

Now I want to verify some inequalities with additional assumptions. A (hopefully) minimal example, showing my problem:

If, for some for input `y` in the function and for some paremeter value `q>0`, it holds that `f[y] >= 2 q`, then I would expect `f[y] >= q` to yield `True`.

However,

```
FullSimplify[f[y] >= q, {f[y] >= 2 q, q > 0}]
```

yields `p^y >= q` instead. Even if I add `q \[Element] Reals` as an assumption.

Do I overlook an obvious mathematical (non-Mathematica) issue, or how I can get Mathematica to "fully" simplify the expression? I have also looked at [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83756/a-better-simplification-function) with `FullSimplify`, but the solution provided did not help.

Comment: Have you tried the functions `ForAll` and `Resolve`?

Comment: I rather seek to verify whether for some specific (not all/arbitrary) values of the parameters certain statements hold true. So as in the example, I have a general function `f`, "local" assumption `f[y]>=2q` with `q>0` and the statement I want to verify, `f[y] >= q`, which I expected to turn into `True`. `ForAll` and `Resolve` don't seem to fare any bettr. I hoped my example was minimalistic enough, I can add more if required.

Comment: I am not sure how capable Mathematica is in solving these kind of analytical questions. It might also be due to the complexity of your function f. Try using `f[x_] := Hold[E^(Log[p] x)]` as your equation, this seems to give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain that this is what you are looking for?

```
f[x_] := p^x
Reduce[f[x] > q && q > 0, p, Reals]
```

Visual:

```
With[
     {f = p^x},
     Manipulate[
      Plot[{f, q}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Orange, Blue}}}],
      {{p, 1/2}, -1, 1},
      {{q, 1/2}, -4, 4}
      ]
     ]
```

Comment: I am not so much interested in the requirements/ranges for the parameters for certain (in)equalities to be true (which, I presume, `Reduce` would give me to some extend), but rather in having local restrictions/assumptions on certain values, then trying to check how these simplify my computations. I.e. "if some statement x holds, can I then infer y"? So I would want to "reduce" w.r.t. **all** parameters, i.e. some sort of "simplifying".