# Reduce doesn't solve this equations with condition

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

```
Reduce[{4==Abs[-1+2 Cos[2A]+2 Cos[2B]+2 Cos[2(A+B)]]},{A,B},Reals]
```

worked well, but

```
Reduce[{4==Abs[-1+2 Cos[2A]+2 Cos[2B]+2 Cos[2(A+B)]],0<A<Pi,0<B<Pi,0<A+B<Pi},{A,B},Reals]
```

given **Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>**

Comment: I think this should have the [bugs] tag. `Reduce[{4 == Abs[-1 + 2 Cos[2 A] + 2 Cos[2 B] + 2 Cos[2 (A + B)]], 0 < B < Pi}, {A, B}, Reals]` raises `Reduce::nsmet`. Replace `0 < B < Pi` with `0 < A < Pi` does not. The expression is symmetric in `A` and `B`.

Comment: Yes, definitely smells like a bug. Even more startling is the fact that the result **depends on the order in which you specify the variables** to solve for: `Reduce[{4 == Abs[-1 + 2 Cos[2 A] + 2 Cos[2 B] + 2 Cos[2 (A + B)]], 0 < B < Pi}, {A, B}, Reals]` returns a solution; the seemingly equivalent `Reduce[{4 == Abs[-1 + 2 Cos[2 A] + 2 Cos[2 B] + 2 Cos[2 (A + B)]], 0 < B < Pi}, {B, A}, Reals]` returns `Reduce::nsmet`! (on MMA 10.2 Win7-64)

Comment: This may be related to [Why does simplification in Mathematica depend on variable names](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22071/27951) and [Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/27951).