# Inconsistency of output format in `Eigenvalue`

Tags: output-formatting

I am bothered by the output format of the last two elements of `efre`. Is there a way to make these two look like the same format as the first two in `efre`?

```
Remove["Global`*"]

coe = k/m SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 
      1} , {4, 4}];
efre = Sqrt[-coe // Eigenvalues] // Simplify 
evec = coe // Eigenvectors // Simplify;
Column[Subscript[ω, #] & /@ Range@4 == efre // Thread, 
 Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `// Simplify ` with `//N// Simplify ` and they look the same.

Comment: @bills Your way somehow works, but what I want is a symbolic expression not the numerical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Remove["Global`*"]

coe = k/m SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 
      1}, {4, 4}];
efre = Sqrt[k/m] *Simplify[Sqrt[-coe // Eigenvalues]/Sqrt[k/m]];
evec = coe // Eigenvectors // Simplify;
Column[Subscript[\[Omega], #] & /@ Range@4 == efre // Thread, 
 Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the only way, although it looks a little bit weird.

Comment: @Lawrence - You can also just leave off the Simplify when defining efre: `efre = Sqrt[-coe // Eigenvalues]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

As Bob Hanlon comments the original output without `Simplify` is already in the form you want:

```
efre = Sqrt[-coe // Eigenvalues]
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m],
>  Sqrt[1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m], 
>  Sqrt[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m],
>  Sqrt[1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m]}
> ```

However, it may help to understand how to work with [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) and [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html).
As elsewhere<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23441/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40484/121)</sup> you need to specify a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) that is closer to the way you see expressions rather than *Mathematica*'s internal one, which is roughly approximated by [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html).

For the sake of an example let's transform our output into a different form so that we can see that `Simplify` has an effect:

```
e2 = ExpandAll //@ efre
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[5/2 + Sqrt[5]/2] Sqrt[k/m], 
>  Sqrt[3/2 + Sqrt[5]/2] Sqrt[k/m],
>  Sqrt[(5 k)/m - (Sqrt[5] k)/m]/Sqrt[2],
>  Sqrt[(3 k)/m - (Sqrt[5] k)/m]/Sqrt[2]}
> ```

Now we `Simplify` with a `ComplexityFunction` that is based on visual output size:

```
Simplify[e2, ComplexityFunction -> Composition[StringLength, ToString]]
```

> ```
> {Sqrt[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m],
>  Sqrt[1/2 (3 + Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m], 
>  Sqrt[1/2 (5 - Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m],
>  Sqrt[1/2 (3 - Sqrt[5])] Sqrt[k/m]}
> ```

Comment: Since you love terse code how about the infix form of `Composition` (`@*`) introduced in **V10**

Comment: @RunnyKine I almost used that but out of sympathy for users of old versions I did not.  Good note however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Great illustrations, thanks! (still reading the document to fully understand these applicaitons)