# Why does this happen with FullSimplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

It is stated at the *Wolfram Documentation Center* ([FullSimplify/Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html)) that:

[image]

Why and when this could happen? How to avoid it? Any patterns?

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, this question is a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption).

Comment: The first examle mighe be `FullSimplify[(1 - b^2)/c^2, c^2 + b^2 == 1]`.

Comment: @Artes yes, it seems that the alphabetic order is the problem. The symbol inside the parenthesis has to come first considering the alphabet order. It's obvious with these examples : `FullSimplify[(1 - abx^2)/aby^2, abx^2 + aby^2 == 1]` and `FullSimplify[(1 - aby^2)/abx^2, abx^2 + aby^2 == 1]`. The first example gives 1 because `abx` is "before" `aby` (if you sort them alphabetically) ...

Comment: Why doesn't Wolfram relabel the symbols, simplify, and restore the original names...?

Comment: I have the impression that this happens because trying out all possible replacements would involve going through large numbers of permutations which would generally lead to a combinatoric explosion. So, some choices have to be made, and not all possible replacements are actually tried.

Comment: Maybe an option should be available for us.

Comment: Closely related: [Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption) (possible duplicate?). There's a solution in 
Mr.Wizards answer.

Comment: That's right. It is a duplicate.