# Is it possible to reach this expression using Mathematica's algebraic functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I know that this expression:

```
-(m-2 r+b^2 (-7 m+6 r)) ((-m+r)^2+b^4 (-2 m+3 r)^2+b^2 (-3 m^2+10 m r-6 r^2))+(1+b^2)^2 m^3 Cos[t]^2
```

Is equal to this one:

```
(1-3 b^2)^3 (-m+r)^2 (-m+2 r)+(1+b^2)^2 m^3 (b^2+Cos[t]^2)
```

I couldn't get Mathematica to reach this simpler later form. FullSimplify and other functions combinations like FullSimplify with PowerExpand didn't work. I even used [VOISImplify](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption/18089#18089), and no success. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think the latter one is "simpler", because it is shorter?

Comment: Change simpler for shorter then. I want a shorter version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr = -(m - 2 r + b^2 (-7 m + 6 r)) ((-m + r)^2 + 
      b^4 (-2 m + 3 r)^2 + 
      b^2 (-3 m^2 + 10 m r - 6 r^2)) + (1 + b^2)^2 m^3 Cos[t]^2;

expr2 = (Collect[expr1 /. Cos[t]^2 -> x - b^2, x] // FullSimplify) /. 
  x -> (b^2 + Cos[t]^2)
```

> (-1 + 3 b^2)^3 (m - 2 r) (m - r)^2 + (1 + b^2)^2 m^3 (b^2 + Cos[t]^2)

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify
```

> True

```
LeafCount /@ {expr, expr2}
```

> {76, 42}

Comment: How did you end with that substitution?

Comment: @Giovanni - `(b^2 + Cos[t]^2)` was the "odd" factor in the last term of the target result so I made the expression a polynomial of that factor.

Comment: Any general procedure for these cases?

Comment: @Giovanni - Not that I know of.