# Simplifying complicated fractions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I need to simplify a long expression with a denominator in the form of `a+b`. To keep it simple, let me replace the long expression with a short example:

```
(e*a + e*b + c + f)/(a + b) // FullSimplify
```

> (c + (a + b) e + f)/(a + b)

This is not a simple form. I'd like to see things like

```
(e*a + e*b + c + d)/(a + b) // FullSimplify
```

> (c + d)/(a + b) + e

But unfortunately, if I replace the `d` with `f`, the simplification does not work.

Is there a universal way to make `FullSimplify` work even harder? By universal I mean I could have simply replaced `d` into `f`. Or I can `Collect` coefficients of `e`. However, in a long expression it is quite hard to make change to all different terms. Also, considering the real expression is long and has a lot of variables, considering permutations of all variables would be exponentially expensive in computation time.

Comment: Closely related: [Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the denominator to a single variable, FullSimplify, and then restore the original denominator.

```
expr = (e*a + e*b + c + f)/(a + b);

((expr /. a -> z - b) // FullSimplify) /. z -> a + b
```

> e + (c + f)/(a + b)