# Collect/Factor a fraction

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization, term-rewriting

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to factor things only containing a specific combination of a fraction, example:

$$\tag{1}f = \frac{a+m\cdot a+b+n\cdot b+c+k\cdot c+d+e}{ab}$$

Is there a way to make Mathematica rewrite $(1)$ as

$$f = \frac{1+n}{a}+\frac{1+m}{b} +\frac{c(1+k)+d+e}{ab}\,~~~~~~~?$$

Comment: Have you tried [`Apart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apart.html)?

Comment: Yes, a simple implementation of Apart doesn't seem to yield the desired expression.

Comment: Here's a similar question but with a sum in the denominator, perhaps this is the way to go. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77370/10325

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider your expression,

```
expr = (a + m a + b + n b + c + k c + d + e)/(a b);
```

This gets us almost where we want to go,

```
Expand@expr
(* 1/a + 1/b + c/(a b) + d/(a b) + e/(a b) + (c k)/(
 a b) + m/b + n/a *)
```

But we have too many terms with the same denominator, so we can use `GatherBy` to group them, then simplify the sums of terms with the same denominator, then sum it all back up,

```
Together@*Plus @@@ GatherBy[List @@ Expand[expr], Denominator] // Total
(* (c + d + e + c k)/(a b) + (1 + m)/b + (1 + n)/a *)
```

But as OP points out, this will not combine terms where the denominator is the same except for a constant factor, like `a/(2*b)` and `c/b`.  This function should be able to simplify an rational expression like desired in the OP (if you come up with a way to break the function, please let me know).

```
fractionExpand[expr_] :=
  Replace[Expand@expr, 
  expr2_Plus :> (Together@*Plus @@@ 
      GatherBy[List @@ expr2, Variables@*Denominator] // Total)]
```

This will break up a term into the largest number of fractions, without repeating denominators.  Here are a few tests,

```
expr2 = (1 + m)/b + (1 + n)/a + (1 + o)/c + (d + e + f g)/(
   a b) + (h + i + j k)/(b c) + (l + p q)/(a b c) // Together
```

[image]

```
fractionExpand@expr2
```

[image]

You get back the original input.

```
expr3 = a/(2 b) + c/b + d/e + f/(g + z) + (a - c)/(l m b) // Together
```

[image]

```
fractionExpand@expr3
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was neat!

Comment: Now that I've played around with your code I notice that terms like 1/(2*b) and 1/(1*b) does not get written together. Your solution still answers the original question but perhaps I should've asked a more general question. Is there a simple way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give an example?  `fractionExpand[2/(1*b) + 2/c + 3/(2 b) + 4/(a b)]` seems to work

Comment: It would be nice if your code somehow differentiated between a variable name and a number such as 2. So that c/(2b)+1/b would read (c+2)/(2b).

Comment: will work on it, gotta leave for the day now though

Comment: OK thanks a lot for all the effort.

Comment: The code is even better now!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that this is better, but just as a version:

```
  expr1 = (a + m a + b + n b + c + k c + d + e);
expr2 = Collect[expr1, {a, b}];
expr3 = Take[expr2, 4];
Map[ReleaseHold, 
  MapAt[Hold, Take[expr2, {5, 6}]/(a*b), {{3, 1}, {3, 2}}] // 
   Apart] + expr3/(a*b)
```

(*  (c + d + e + c k)/(a b) + (1 + m)/b + (1 + n)/a  *)

Have fun!