# Mathematica can't simplify disguised expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

When I simplify the following quartic polynomial with a linear constraint;

`Simplify[x y z a + x y z b , a + b + c == 0] // Expand`

I get what to me seems like the most simple form

`-c x y z`

Now I disguise the problem a little;

`Simplify[Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3] Subscript[k, 
     2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 3] Subscript[k, 
     2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
     1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2] + 
   Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3] Subscript[k, 
     2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 3] Subscript[k, 
     3]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
     1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2], 
  Subscript[k, 2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] + 
    Subscript[k, 3]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] + 
    Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] == 
   0] // Expand`

And Mathematica no longer makes any simplification, I just get out what I put in

`Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3] Subscript[k, 
   2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 3] Subscript[k, 
   2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
   1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2] + 
 Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3] Subscript[k, 
   2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 3] Subscript[k, 
   3]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 4] Subscript[\[Epsilon], 
   1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[\[Epsilon], 2]`

I do have some rules defined for `\[CircleDot]` which make it like an inner product, but I don't think that should affect this situation.

To me, I have asked Mathematica to do exactly the same thing twice. Why can it not do it the second time?

Comment: Could you get rid of the fancy formatting? Especially subscripts etc are a pain to parse quickly on this site.

Comment: Try also `Simplify[x y z d + x y z e , d + e + c == 0]`...

Comment: I don't think `Simplify` is familiar with inner products.

Comment: Well the formatting appears to me to be what is causing the problem Yves.
Ah that's interesting Marius thanks for the extra example. So do you know how to teach Mathematica that the one with only one term is more simple?
Daniel, I'm not asking it simplify the inner products

Comment: Using [`VOISimplify`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18089/14303): `VOISimplify[{Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2]}, 
 exprFromOP, assumptionFromOP]` gives desired result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.