# Simplify x+y=5 fails with assumption y = 2x, but works with x = 2y. Why?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am trying to understand how assumptions and simplification works with this simple example:

> x+y=5, assume x = 2y

So I write:

```
Assuming[x == 2y, Simplify[x+y==5]]
```

And the result makes sense to me:

```
3y == 5
```

But then if want to do

> x+y=5, assume y = 2x

and I write:

```
Assuming[y == 2x, Simplify[x+y==5]]
```

I get:

```
x+y==5
```

when I should be getting:

```
3x==5
```

Why?

**Update:** I know this works: `Simplify[x + y == 5] /. y -> 2 x` what I want to understand is why Assuming does what it does: Am I using it wrong somehow?

I now tried: `Assuming[q == 2 p, Simplify[p + q == 5]]` vs `Assuming[p == 2 q, Simplify[p + q == 5]]` same issue, I am starting to wonder if it has something to do with alphabetical order of the name of the variables.

Comment: `Simplify` measures "simplicity" via the measure ``Simplify`SimplifyCount[expr]``.  None of the three expressions is simpler than the other by this measure.  So any of the three answers would be acceptable to `Simplify`.  (It is odd that in one case the original is chosen and in the other, the equivalent is.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for commenting, to be clear, this is not the only case Assuming acts weirdly, this is just the simplest example I could come up with

Comment: I guess there is something else to it, otherwise there would be no difference between in the output of the 2 assumptions

Comment: I tried Reduce and the following happens. This command Assuming[y == 2 x, Reduce[x + y == 5]] // Simplify does not give anything, while this one again gives the correct result Reduce[x + y == 5] /. y -> 2 x // Simplify. Can it have to do with replacement rules by Mma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael E2 points out, your results have equal complexity according to *Mathematica*'s default metric. When there's more than one answer, which one *Mathematica* chooses may depend on its canonical ordering of expressions. You can get it to prefer to eliminate symbols by defining your own `ComplexityFunction`.

```
cf[e_] := Count[e, _Symbol, All]
```

But then:

```
Assuming[y == 2 x, Simplify[x + y == 5, ComplexityFunction -> cf]]
(* 3 y == 10 *)
```

It seems to implicitly prefer `y` to `x`, presumably because `y` comes later in the alphabet.

Comment: Yes, looks like it is the same issue described here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption?rq=1