# Renaming one parameter changes the result of Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics

Surely the following couple of expressions should both output `True`:

```
Simplify[
  PDF[TransformedDistribution[(A + B)/2, {A, B} \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{{L, H}, {L, H}}]], t] == 
  PDF[TriangularDistribution[{L, H}], t], L < t < H]
```

and

```
Simplify[
  PDF[TransformedDistribution[(A + B)/2, {A, B} \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{{L, U}, {L, U}}]], t] == 
  PDF[TriangularDistribution[{L, U}], t], L < t < U]
```

They aren't. At least not on my version 11.1.1.0. Only the first expression outputs `True`.

Comment: Note that `PDF[TransformedDistribution[(A + B)/2, {A, B}  UniformDistribution[{{L, U}, {L, U}}]], (L + U)/2]` yields `(2 U)/(L - U)^2` (in V11.3), which is nonsense because when `L` and `U` are changed by any common addition the PDF should remain unchanged.

Comment: Maybe an inconsistency but not a bug.  Instead of `U` if you pick any letter (a, b, c,...k, C, D,...,K) "below" `L`, then you end up with `True`.  Choose any letter instead of `U` "above" `L` and you'll not get `True`.  And don't use the `bugs` tag until you get confirmation from others that it is a bug.

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:bugs] tag before using it.

Comment: @JimB Why would you not consider it a bug though? Surely the result of a calculation like this should not depend on the choice of variable names?

Comment: @MarcoB While I'd certainly like to see it consistent, the "non-True" answer that the OP failed to produce is `L == 0 || L + U != 2 t` which is not `False`.  So rather than "bug", I'd call it "not so desirable" or "inconvenient" in the scheme of things.

Comment: Unfortunately the lexical order of variable names affects the outcome of `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` and `Reduce`. This has be known for a long time. See [this post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Apr/msg00384.html) from 2006.

Comment: Question with answers relevant to this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926