# FullSimplify output depends on symbol name

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Using g rather than b as variable name changes output. As far as I know neither b nor g are restricted symbols. Can this be reproduced on other builds? Using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on a Mac.

```
Quit[]

FullSimplify[-c d b + a f b]

(* b (-c d + a f)*) 

FullSimplify[-c d g + a f g]

(* -c d g + a f g *)
```

Comment: Can reproduce. It seems to have something to do with the symbol sorting that Mathematica does for `Plus` and `Times`.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why.

Comment: This is very likely not a bug. Sensitivity to symbol naming is a well-known behaviour stemming from expression canonicalization (what Sjoerd said). Note that `FullSimplify` does not guarantee a simpler output. It tries a few transformations and if it finds a simpler version, it outputs it.

Comment: How to work around it? This example is trivial but the behaviour is sometimes very inconvenient.

Comment: You should include that comment in the question itself, but please try to make it more specific. What exactly do you mean by "working around it"? Can you give representative examples of the expressions you are dealing with? There is not going to be a general method that makes `FullSimplify` not sensitive to symbol naming, but there may be ways to deal with the specific cases you need.

Comment: Some relevant information [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18089) and [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Jan/msg00237.html).