# Change a single letter changes the result

Tags: simplifying-expressions

these two codes give different result.

```
FullSimplify[a-b,Assumptions->a==1+y&&b==1+y-x]
```

this give `x`

```
FullSimplify[a-z,Assumptions->a==1+y&&z==1+y-x]
```

but just convert b to z,result is `a - z`

why does this happen?

mathematica version:11.3

Comment: It is likely to be a bug. That said, you should be using With for your case. Assumptions is more for things like x is an element of Reals, x > 0  etc..I mean your could looks much better as With [{a = 1, z = 1 - x}, a - z]

Comment: closely related/possible duplicate: [Why does Simplify ignore an assumption?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17926/125)