# FullSimplify, Assumptions: Replacing Complex expressions by Simpler Ones as per Leaf Count

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have been trying to simplify equations using Mathematica of the following basic form:
$$\text{FullSimplify}\left[x^2+y^2,\text{Assumptions}\to x^2+y^2==c^2\right]$$
With the output being,
$$x^2+y^2$$

```
FullSimplify[x^2 + y^2, Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 == c^2]
```

However, if $c$ were a number, the expected result is obtained ie. $c^{2}$. I would like to know how to make Mathematica replace the more complex(as per Leaf count) LHS with the simpler RHS.

Comment: Convert the assumption to a replacement rule, e.g., `expr /. y^2 :> c^2 - x^2`

Comment: My example was a representative of the complex. In general, I'm not sure how this will work. For example, say I have $ab+cd==ef+gh$. Then, I would expect $ab+cd$ to remain unchanged. However, say if it were $ab+cd+ef==gh$, then I would expect $ab+cd+ef$ to be replaced.

Comment: @Gattu A replacement will work for the example you gave. Perhaps you could show a more representative example. Maybe you could use an intermediate value: `Simplify[x^2 + y^2, Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 == m]` returns `m` and then you could replace `m` with `c^2` in the resulting expression.

Comment: Alternatively, use the rule as a replacement-function for the TransformationFunction option like so: `FullSimplify[x^2+y^2,TransformationFunctions->{(#/.(x^2+y^2)->c^2)&}]`

Comment: @MarcoB's solution is explained, somewhat, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-does-simplify-ignore-an-assumption)