# Simplifying expressions with head Max

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

(I saw: [Unable to evaluate reasonable max expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11111/unable-to-evaluate-reasonable-max-expression) but this seems an even easier case an I thought it worth posting)

See the following simplifications of Max operators, which are all very straightforward:

```
Assuming[b/g >= l n (1 - t), Max[b/g, l n (1 - t)] // FullSimplify]
(* Doesn't simplify *)

Assuming[b >= l n (1 - t), Max[b, l n (1 - t)] // FullSimplify]
(* Simplifies when I remove the /g *)

Assuming[b >= g l n (1 - t), Max[b, g l n (1 - t)] // FullSimplify]
(* Doesn't simplify.  Added an additional 'g' was enough*)

Assuming[b/g >= l n, Max[b/g, l n] // FullSimplify] 
(* Simplifies, even with the /g on both sides, but had to remove the (1-t)*)
```

Basically, the cases with which it works are very trivial, for seamingly trivial expressions.  Any ideas on how to tell mathematica to work harder on the simplifications (the trick in [Unable to evaluate reasonable max expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11111/unable-to-evaluate-reasonable-max-expression) didn't seem to work here).

While I have tried to get things down to a minimal working example, my setup is slightly more complicated, but of this pattern.  Adding additional parameter assumptions didn't seem to help. Here is my full test, adding an `If` version since it is equivalent here.:

```
Assuming[(lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η) <= b/(1 + g ), 
  Max[b/(1 + g), (lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η)] // FullSimplify]

Assuming[(lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η) <= b/(1 + g), 
  If[b/(1 + g) >= (lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η),
    b/(1 + g), (Λ (1 - θ) η lh)/(1 + η)] // FullSimplify]
```

Comment: Is this sufficient? It seems to work for the examples you showed. simpMax[u_, v_] := Simplify[If[u >= v, u, v]]; {Assuming[b/g >= l n (1 - t), simpMax[b/g, l n (1 - t)]],
 Assuming[b >= l n (1 - t), simpMax[b, l n (1 - t)]],
 Assuming[b >= g l n (1 - t), simpMax[b, g l n (1 - t)]],
 Assuming[b/g >= l n, simpMax[b/g, l n]]}

Comment: @bill Thanks so much for the response!  The `If` formulation seems to work much better for simplifications, and this passes my more advanced test above.  If you create an answer, I can mark it as complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 15]
```

Default value of this suboption is 4.

```
Assuming[b/g >= l n (1 - t), Max[b/g, l n (1 - t)] // FullSimplify]
```

> b/g

```
Assuming[b >= g l n (1 - t), Max[b, g l n (1 - t)] // FullSimplify]
```

> b

```
Assuming[(lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η) <= b/(1 + g), 
    Max[b/(1 + g), (lh η (1 - θ) Λ)/(1 + η)] // FullSimplify]
```

> b/(1 + g)

To reset the suboption to its original value:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4]
```