# What is the list of all Heads that Collect threads over?

Tags: undocumented, rule

After spending hours of debugging my program, I found that `Collect` threads over `Rule`.  While the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html) (under Details and Options) says that it threads over "lists ... equations, inequalities and logic functions", `Rule` does not count (in my mind) as one of those.

In order to avoid any further unexpected behavior, I need to know exactly which heads `Collect` threads over.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Does `SystemOptions["AlgebraicThreadThroughHeads"]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr Yes! It does.  Please add that as an answer, and also include how you knew where to find that information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SystemOptions["AlgebraicThreadThroughHeads"]
```

> {"AlgebraicThreadThroughHeads" ->
>      {And, Equal, Greater, GreaterEqual, 
>      Implies, Inequality, Less, LessEqual, List, Nand, Nor, Not, Or, 
>      Rule, Unequal, Xor}}

Comment: It was pure lock that I bumped into the option `"AlgebraicThreadThroughHeads"` while checking `"SimplificationOptions"` for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149955/125):)